# react-native clearInterval doesnt work in android

Tags: javascript, react-native

this is my code, everything is good except stopTimer method which includes clearInterval:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.insertArray();
  that = this;

  this.setState({
    interval: setInterval(function() {
      let elapsed_time=(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)) - that.state.data;
      that.setState({
        elapsed: that.secondsToHms(elapsed_time)
      });
    }, 1000)
  });     
}

secondsToHms(d){
  d = Number(d);
  var h = Math.floor(d/3600);
  var m = Math.floor(d%3600/60);
  var s = Math.floor(d%3600%60);

  return ('0' + h).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + m).slice(-2) + ":"+ ('0' + s).slice(-2);
}

stopTimer(){
  clearInterval(this.state.interval);
}
```

thats how I call stopTimer method:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.stopTimer()>  
 <Text>stopTimer</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: The first thing you need to learn to do is to cleanly format your code. Use proper spacing, don't mix single and double quotes. Because your code is messily formatted, you're not seeing the missing + in the return statement in secondsToHms

Comment: thanks,  fixed that but still I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

State is not the right place to store such a reference. It does not represent the state of your view.

Since there is no quick clean way to do this, keep the reference of the timeout in this, this being your component. It will work on Android.

`this.interval = setInterval(function() {})`

Also, do not forget to clear when componentWillUnmount is triggered.